# How do I vertically center my li's in my ul in my header?

Tags: html, css, header, html-lists, vertical-alignment

I want to vertically center my li's in my header's ul.
You can check out the JSBin here: http://jsbin.com/xeven/1/edit

I don't see what I'm doing wrong here? Can someone help me?
I would also like to center the whole thing... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change your `.header ul li` rule to:

```
.header ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-left: 35px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MZGd9/)**

I removed the float rule and changed the display type from table-cell to inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an inner header with fixed width and center it. 
This way the background with still fill the 100% width of the screen but you will be able to center the menu.

HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="inner-header">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">
          <div id="logo">BASE</div>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.inner-header{
  margin:0 auto;
  width:400px;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/xeven/3/edit